# org.json avoid deserializing null fields into JSONObject.Null

Tags: java, json, jsonschema, org.json

I'm using org.json with https://github.com/everit-org/json-schema in order to validate json files before to store them in a database.

```
String schemaString = readSchemaFromUrl(urlToRootSchema, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
String jsonString = readFile(pathToJson, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
JSONObject rawSchema = new JSONObject(new JSONTokener(schemaString));
Schema schema = SchemaLoader.load(rawSchema);
try {
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonString);
    schema.validate(json); // throws a ValidationException if this object is invalid
}
```

Validation fails because of json files containing `null` values. Those `null` values are are deserialized into `JSONObject.Null`.

According [to this](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html), this behaviour is expected:

> Warning: this class represents null in two incompatible ways: the standard Java null reference, and the sentinel value NULL. In particular, calling put(name, null) removes the named entry from the object but put(name, JSONObject.NULL) stores an entry whose value is JSONObject.NULL

**Is there a way to prevent org.json deserializing "null" value?**